# User making requests on server without logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, asp.net-identity

I've had some weird activity going on in my Azure Cloud Service and I've noticed upon checking the IIS logs that a bunch of bogus accounts have been making a pattern of requests. I'm using ASP.NET Identity as my authentication framework, and I've determined these users are not logging in by checking the LastLoginDate field in my DB.

Every controller in my app has an Authorize tag excluding the Login and Register actions - and the fact that the IIS logs are showing the user name in the request hints that they are indeed going through.

Can anyone offer insight on how these requests are going through? I would like to be able to flag these malicious accounts and proceed accordingly.

I've attached a screenshot of a recent IIS log:

[image]

Comment: They were making requests, but did they get any response?

Comment: Not sure. I don't know how else the system would be able to log an error with their username: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: Are you sure that's the username you see? IIS logs won't be showing Identity usernames.

Comment: @trailmax I have an Error class in my app that logs errors to the db and I'm seeing the identity user in the record. The error being logged is 'Object reference not set to instance of object'. Likely a code issue but nonetheless it matches the user names in the IIS logs.